# Linq to Entities, getting Max date when there is no data

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Here's my statement:

```
startDate = (from n in db.Nodes 
where n.SeedID == mySeedID select n.CreatedDate).Max<DateTime>();
```

It works fine when there is data for that SeedID. However, some times the seed is new, so there are no nodes. The statement results in an InvalidOperationException. I could wrap this in try/catch. Is there a better way to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a nullable DateTime?

```
startDate = (from n in db.Nodes 
             where n.SeedID == mySeedID 
             select (DateTime?)n.CreatedDate).Max<DateTime?>();
```